# Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 installer stuck at "The installer is probing for block devices to install to."

Tags: server, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on a VM under Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2019.

I've had problems in the past where I wasn't able to complete the installation, I managed to get around that by installing another version of Ubuntu server, but I want to install the latest LTS now as I'm having trouble with 21.10.

After setting up my keyboard layout, networking and the proxy a page saying that "The installer is probing for block devices to install to." and to "Please wait until it completes." was shown to me but it has now been stuck like this for a good part of 10 minutes. I could not find anyone else having the same problem as me (being stuck on that screen as opposed to having an error message after it).

I was hoping anyone could help me figure out what is exactly going on. This is the screen that I'm referring to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQwC1.png

The screen is not frozen as the loading "dot" is moving around lag-free: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgKpB.png

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have resolved my issue just by going back and hitting continue again.

Comment: Yes, my one also worked after going back and continuing again.